# Using Hooks along with Redux---Bad Practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, lodash, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement a sorted table as shown in the Semantic UI Docs.

https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table/#variations-sortable

I'm using redux on my project and confused as to how I should implement both the sorted tables and my search input function.

On page load I am storing all data in a state called baseball. I also have a cardsToShow state which is updated if a user is searching for something, triggered by searchCards function. The cardsToShow state is what I'm using to display my data.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    baseball: state.baseball,
    cardsToShow: searchCards(state)
  };
};

const searchCards = ({ baseball, search }) => {
  return search
    ? baseball.filter(a =>
        a.title[0].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      )
    : baseball;
};
```

In the Semantic UI/Lodash example, they update and sort the data state when a user clicks a column.

I've tried to replicate this using some state hooks for the column, direction and filteredData fields.

```
const Cards = props => {
  const [column, setColumn] = useState(null);
  const [direction, setDirection] = useState(null);
  const [filteredData, setData] = useState(props.cardsToShow);

  const handleSort = clickedColumn => {
    if (column !== clickedColumn) {
      setColumn(clickedColumn);
      setData(_.sortBy(filteredData, [clickedColumn]));
      setDirection("ascending");
      return;
    }

    setData(_.sortBy(filteredData.reverse()));
    direction === "ascending"
      ? setDirection("descending")
      : setDirection("ascending");
  };
```

This is also what my column header looks like:

```
  <Table.HeaderCell
                    sorted={column === "title" ? direction : null}
                    onClick={handleSort("title")}
                  >
                    Card Title
                  </Table.HeaderCell>
```

First of all, i'm getting a 'Too many re-renders' error on the code above which is one problem.  But the main issue is that I now have a filteredData field which I'm updating ....yet I have the other state cardsToShow.

I know whatever I'm doing is here is wrong, but curious to see if anyone has any guidance as to how to best accomplish this.  Is it acceptable to use hooks like this, along with having a redux store which holds your global state?  Or should i somehow create another reducer for the sorting that I'm trying to do?  Thanks.

---EDIT--UPDATED COMPONENT BELOW

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Search from "./Search";
import TimeAgo from "react-timeago";
import { useSelector} from "react-redux";
import { Table } from "semantic-ui-react";
import _ from "lodash";
// import { useField } from "../hooks";

const searchCards = ({ baseball, search }) => {
  return search
    ? baseball.filter(a =>
        a.title[0].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      )
    : baseball;
};

const Cards = () => {
  const baseball = useSelector(state => state.baseball);
  const search = useSelector(state => state.search);
  const cardsToShow = searchCards(baseball, search);
  const [column, setColumn] = useState(null);
  const [direction, setDirection] = useState(null);
  const [filteredData, setData] = useState(cardsToShow);

  const handleSort = clickedColumn => {
    if (column !== clickedColumn) {
      setColumn(clickedColumn);
      setData(_.sortBy(filteredData, [clickedColumn]));
      setDirection("ascending");
      return;
    }

    setData(_.sortBy(filteredData.reverse()));
    direction === "ascending"
      ? setDirection("descending")
      : setDirection("ascending");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Search />
        <h3>Vintage Card Search</h3>
        <Table sortable celled fixed striped>
          <Table.Header>
            <Table.Row>
              <Table.HeaderCell
                sorted={column === "title" ? direction : null}
                onClick={handleSort("title")}
              >
                Card Title
              </Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell># Bids</Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell>Watchers</Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell>Price</Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell>Time Left</Table.HeaderCell>
            </Table.Row>
          </Table.Header>
          <Table.Body>
            {filteredData.map(card => (
              <>
                <Table.Row key={card.id}>
                  <Table.Cell>{card.title}</Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell>
                    {card.sellingStatus[0].bidCount
                      ? card.sellingStatus[0].bidCount
                      : 0}
                  </Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell>
                    {card.listingInfo[0].watchCount
                      ? card.listingInfo[0].watchCount
                      : 0}
                  </Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell>
                    $
                    {card.sellingStatus &&
                      card.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0]["__value__"]}
                  </Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell>
                    <TimeAgo
                      date={new Date(
                        card.listingInfo && card.listingInfo[0].endTime
                      ).toLocaleDateString()}
                    />
                  </Table.Cell>
                </Table.Row>
              </>
            ))}
          </Table.Body>
        </Table>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Cards;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead using Redux as you were used, try the new Redux implementation in hooks in this way:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {useSelector } from "react-redux";

const searchCards = (baseball, search) => {
  return search
    ? baseball.filter(a =>
        a.title[0].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      )
    : baseball;
};

export const Cards = () => {
  const baseball = useSelector(state => state.baseball);
  const search = useSelector(state => state.search);
  const cardsToShow = searchCards(baseball, search);
  const [column, setColumn] = useState(null);
  const [direction, setDirection] = useState(null);
  const [filteredData, setData] = useState(cardsToShow);

  const handleSort = clickedColumn => {
    if (column !== clickedColumn) {
      setColumn(clickedColumn);
      setData(_.sortBy(filteredData, [clickedColumn]));
      setDirection("ascending");
      return;
    }

    setData(_.sortBy(filteredData.reverse()));
    direction === "ascending"
      ? setDirection("descending")
      : setDirection("ascending");
  };

  return {filteredData, handleSort};
};
```

From what you explain you want to achieve I find you need to export the `filteredData` element (the baseball cards to show already filtered and sorted) and the `handleSort` method to be able to trigger the changes from your `Table` component.
I don't think you would need to store in Redux again the filtered and sorted elements. Using `reselect` and memoizing the selector should be enough if you want to go that way and improve the performance.

Comment: thank you dez...this is great stuff.  one quick question--i implemented your suggestions and I updated my OP with the component code.  mind taking a quick look at that, to see where I might be going wrong?  i'm getting a cannot read on the map statement

Comment: Pay attention to the `searchCard` function arguments. You are passing them as 2 independent arguments and in your definition of the function you try to use them as properties of an object argument, so that would make them `null` getting a `null` in `cardsToShow` setting another `null` to `filteredData`. I fixed that problem you had in my example.

Comment: oh boy i'm still confused..sorry....should clarify that I have a 'search' state which is just a search term from a different Search component.  that's why i created the useSelector for search.  in your example, you use `state.cards.baseball` and i'm not sure what that is..that's why i changed it.  when i use your code, i get `Cannot read property 'baseball' of undefined.`

Comment: i also scrapped my redux state and dispatch functions for this component (which i think what you were alluding to in your initial comments

Comment: Sorry about that mistake. I thought you had stored your `baseball` data in a reducer called `cards`. Yes, remove it like: `  const baseball = useSelector(state => state.baseball);`. Didn't know you have the `search` stored as a field in your Redux state. Then you would need to change your code and use `useDispatch` to execute the actions in the new way, like the action to set the `search` in your store.

Comment: no worries...oh no even more confused :(  so you are saying i would need to scrap all this code?

Comment: No! Code looks good, just explaining what would you need to be able to interact with the Redux store, replacing the old `dispatch` actions of Redux for the new `useDispatch` hook. [Reference](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#usedispatch)

Comment: Okay so instead of state using the books, create a few reducers and dispatch actions to reducers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202942/discussion-between-dez-and-john-rogerson).